# Pandas: consolidate datetime intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe representing the start and end time of some kind of event, e.g., when a machine in a factory has been stopped:

```
     machine_id            start_date              end_date
1             1   2016-10-01 00:00:00   2016-10-01 03:00:00
2             1   2016-10-03 05:30:00   2016-10-03 06:30:00
3             2   2016-10-03 23:30:00   2016-10-04 01:00:00
4             1   2016-10-04 05:00:00   2016-10-04 06:00:00
5             2   2016-10-04 05:50:00   2016-10-04 06:00:00
6             1   2016-10-05 18:50:00   2016-10-06 02:00:00
....
```

I need to get the total minutes in which any machine has been stopped, grouped by a given granularity: monthly, weekly, daily... For example, if the granularity is daily, the desired output would be:

```
        date       total_time
1 2016-10-01              180
2 2016-10-02                0
3 2016-10-03               90
4 2016-10-04              130
5 2016-10-05              310
6 2016-10-06              120
...
```

If the granularity were monthly, the output would just be:

```
        date       total_time
1 2016-10-01              830
```

My intuition says that it probably has something to do with `resample()`, but I don't know how to work with `resample` and two different columns.

Comment: Sounds like you want timedelta's between stop and start dates, no?

Comment: Yes, of course. The problem is how to "break" that deltas in days, weeks, months... given that a machine could be stopped more than a day, week or month.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to be able to give accurate calendar-time metrics? Months may be tricky because the number of days in a month depends on the context. Ordinarily, `relativedelta`s hold time in terms of days and seconds only, which I think is the appropriate way to do it in this case. If needed, you could convert days/seconds into relevant minutes/hours/weeks/months as well. In other words, store deltas in the smallest relevant time unit, then convert as needed.

Comment: It's not clear, from your input and your expected output, what exactly you need. Can you explain or even better paste realistic input/output values?

Comment: I've updated the examples, with easier inputs and a real output.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `groupby`?

```
In [67]: df = pandas.read_csv('data', parse_dates=[1, 2])

In [68]: for d, dfg in df.groupby(lambda i: df.end_date[i].date()):
    ...:     print d, (dfg.end_date - dfg.start_date).sum()
    ...: 
2016-10-03 0 days 08:27:23
2016-10-04 1 days 14:00:04
2016-10-31 56 days 19:26:40.344080
```

I am not sure what you mean "when the machine has been stopped": presumably, you mean when a certain even has been triggered. If so, just filter `df` before the above grouping.

Comment: No, thats not what I need. You've got `2016-10-31 56 days 19:26:40.344080`. I'd need that splitted by day (or month). i.e: 56 rows of one day.

Comment: Just remove the `sum()` then.